# Debug Failure. Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I am facing the following error:

```
connect-43d439c034e475bba644.chunk.js:10 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
    at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirective (:3000/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42537:18)
    at :3000/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/servicesHost.js:373:77
    at :3000/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/servicesHost.js:95:142
    at Array.map ()
    at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirectives (:3000/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/servicesHost.js:95:125)
    at actualResolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (:3000/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116674:163)
    at resolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (:3000/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116974:26)
    at processTypeReferenceDirectives (:3000/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118456:31)
    at findSourceFileWorker (:3000/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118341:21)
    at findSourceFile (:3000/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:118196:26)
    at ./app/javascript/connect/index.ts (connect-43d439c034e475bba644.chunk.js:10:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79:1)
    at ./app/javascript/packs/connect.js (connect.js:7:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79:1)
    at 1 (log$:23:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at connect-43d439c034e475bba644.chunk.js:1:57
```

At this point, I've tried almost everything:

updating ts-node
updating typescript
updating ts-loader

And yet, nothing seems to solve this problem.

At this point, I think it's not strictly TS related, but I'm not sure. Here are the versions of my packages:

```
{
  "name": "Angular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-cool/inline-edit-field": "^1.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2",
    "uppy": "0.23.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "html-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.3.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "acorn": "^6.4.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.3",
    "kind-of": "^6.0.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
}
```

If anyone could give me some advice on what to look for right now, or what might be wrong, I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to my issue
the problem was with some dependencies they were taking a greater version as they should have been cuz i was using `'^ X.X.X'`

i had to set  `"typescript": "4.3.5",` instead of `"typescript": "^4.2",` etc ...

Answer (score 0):

For me I was able to get around this by running

```
npx ts-node ./test.ts
```

instead of

```
ts-node ./test.ts
```